# How to Return an Ending Balance in Laravel 7

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have 2 tables namely `deposits` and `withdrawals` tables. I have a dashboard blade file to show the total deposited amount and the `ending balance` which adds `deposited` amount and `annual return`. Now whenever a withdrawal is made, I want to show a correct ending balance. Also when a new deposit was made, it will still reflect on the `ending balance`. So basically, the ending balance would reflect the current balance after deposit and withdrawal.

[image]

So I have these schema on my tables

Deposits table

```php
Schema::create('money_trade_deposits', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->string('mt_dep_number');
    // $table->unsignedBigInteger('money_trade_id');
    $table->integer('amount');
    $table->string('payment_method');
    // $table->foreign('money_trade_id')->references('id')->on('money_trades')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Withdrawals table

```php
Schema::create('withdrawals', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('w_number');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->string('bank');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('account_name');
    $table->string('account_number');
    $table->string('mt_account');
    $table->integer('balance');
    $table->string('amount');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I have separate controllers `MoneyTradeDepositController` and `WithdrawalController`
MoneyTradeDepositController

```php
class MoneyTradeDepositController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request);
        $request->validate([
            'amount' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:2000000', 'min:500'],
            'payment_method' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        ]);

        $moneyTradeDeposit = new MoneyTradeDeposit();

        $moneyTradeDeposit->mt_dep_number = uniqid('MTDepNumber-');
        $moneyTradeDeposit->amount = $request->input('amount');
        $moneyTradeDeposit->payment_method = $request->input('payment_method');
        // $moneyTradeDeposit->money_trade_id = moneytrade()->id();
        $moneyTradeDeposit->user_id = auth()->id();

        // dd($moneyTradeDeposit);
        $moneyTradeDeposit->save();

        return redirect()->route('mt.deposit')->withMessage('Added a New Deposit');
    }
}
```

WithdrawalController

```php
class WithdrawalController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'bank' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'account_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'account_number' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'mt_account' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'balance' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'amount' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        ]);

        $amountSum = MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount');
        $balance = $amountSum + ($amountSum * 12 / 100);

        $withdrawal = new Withdrawal();

        $withdrawal->w_number = uniqid('WNumber-');
        $withdrawal->bank = $request->input('bank');
        $withdrawal->email = $request->input('email');
        $withdrawal->account_name = $request->input('account_name');
        $withdrawal->account_number = $request->input('account_number');
        $withdrawal->mt_account = $request->input('mt_account');
        $withdrawal->balance = $balance - ($request->input('balance'));
        $withdrawal->amount = $request->input('amount');
        $withdrawal->user_id = auth()->id();

        $withdrawal->save();

        return redirect()->route('home.withdrawal')->withMessage('Withdrawal Successful');
    }
}
```

And my blade view is as showing the ending balance as follows

```xml
<div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-success text-uppercase mb-1">Ending Balance</div>
<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php {{  ($amountSum + ($amountSum * 12 / 100))}}</div>
```

I'm showing it using a public function on my HomeController which shows as

```php
public function dashboard()
{
    $moneytrades = MoneyTrade::all();
    $moneytradeDeposits = MoneyTradeDeposit::all();
    $amountSum = MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount');
    $withdrawal = Withdrawal::all();

    return view('dashboard', compact('moneytrades', 'moneytradeDeposits', 'amountSum', 'withdrawal'));
}
```

As of now the `ending balance` is just the sum of the deposited amount row + the annual return. How can I do this relating 2 tables even if multiple deposits and withdrawals are made? Sorry for my poor grammar. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is always best to show us the code

Comment: Indeed, we'd need to see your code and also, if you could explain how the image is related to the issue, that would help as well.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have updated my question with the codes. If you could spare some time to check, that would be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Let me know If  I got it right, After deposit and withdrawal, you are not seeing a real-time change in ending balance  , and it is only visible if you are refreshing the page. Is this your problem ?

Comment: Sorry but no. Currently, the `ending balance` showing is only based the sum of deposits + the annual return amount value. Since it's only based on my `deposits` table, it's not reflecting the correct ending balance when a withdrawal was made. Thus, I want to connect my `deposits` table and my my `withdrawals` table so whenever I make a withdrawal or deposit, it should reflect the correct amount. Just like in bank. Thanks

Comment: so basically you want to check both the changes in `deposits` & `withdrawals` table , If you want to calculate the amount at runtime use both table data in calculate in controller & then show the data or do you want to check whenever a amount is changed in any of the table you want to correspondingly change data in anny other table as well, for that you will require a event listener

Comment: @bhucho the 2nd one is the one I have in mind. Like when the user make a new deposit which should add to the ending balance and if a withdrawal was made, it should minus from the ending balance. How can I use an event listener to connect 2 tables?

Comment: Would this solve your problem? `$amountSum = MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount') - Withdrawal::sum('amount');`

Comment: @IGP that worked for a single withdrawal and when I do anothere deposit. However when I do multiple withdrawals, the computation gets incorrect and it keeps on subtracting until I get a negative amount.

Comment: @Jemy doesn't that mean you're allowing people to withdraw without first checking if there are enough funds?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses guys. I was able to solve my problem using the suggestion below with the line of code `$ending_balance  = (MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount') - 
Withdrawal::sum('amount')) + $annul_return;`. Be safe everyone and have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need `ending_balance = total_deposited-total_witdhrowal + annual_return`

This can be achieved in the home controller as

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $moneytrades = MoneyTrade::all();
    $moneytradeDeposits = MoneyTradeDeposit::all();
    $amountSum = MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount');
    $withdrawal = Withdrawal::all();
    $ending_balance  = (MoneyTradeDeposit::sum('amount') - 
Withdrawal::sum('amount')) + $annul_return;
    return view('dashboard', compact('moneytrades', 'moneytradeDeposits', 'amountSum', 'withdrawal','ending_balance'));
}
```

Then in the blade file just print $ending_balance.
Also In your `WithdrawalController`, I am not able to find any validation regarding the maximum Withdrawable amount  , You should add a condition there something like

```
if $balance > $amount { add withdraw entry into db } else { show error msg};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're such a gem. This solved my problem. :D

Comment: I am glad it helped. :D